# Determining who last modified file in C#

Tags: c#, azure, winforms

I have a C# app that goes through a list of files and determines who modified each file last. I had been doing it using these lines:

```
FileSecurity fileSecurity = file.GetAccessControl();
IdentityReference owner = fileSecurity.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount));
```

This gave me the company domain\username.  I just got a new PC and it seems we've moved away from the domain usage to Azure AD so these lines of code do not work any longer.  I get an error saying "some or all identity references could not be translated".

Is there another way I can determine who modified a file last?  I have searched around a lot but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your new PC basically lacks the domain access your old PC depends on to run your code with respect to your expectation